# Script VBS para alterar o nome do computador

Tags: vbscript

Eu tenho este código que verifica o nome do computador e o altera, mas não está mudando, me informa:

> *Erro linha 29, caractere 5, Objeto necessário:*

```
Dim objShell
Do
    Choice = InputBox("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER. . ." & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    " 1 -  Check PC Name" & vbCrlf & _
    " 2 -  Change PC Name" & vbCrlf & _
    " 3 -  EXIT", _
      "MENU")
    
    If (Choice <> vbNull) and (Choice <> "") Then
        Select Case Choice
           Case 1
               Rem Gets the name of the Computer
               set WshNetwork=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
               strComputerName=WshNetwork.ComputerName
               Wscript.Echo strComputerName
           Case 2
               Dim Input
               Input = InputBox ("Enter Name", "New Name")
           If Input = "" Then
               MsgBox "Change Canceled!"
           Else
               'MsgBox ("You typed :" & Input)
               set Objshel=WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
               ObjShell.run"wmic computersystem where name=""%computername%"" call rename name=""& Input"""
               Set objshel=Nothing
           End If
           Case 3
               WScript.Quit
           Case Else
                'Wscript.Echo "bye"
        End Select
    End If
Loop Until Choice = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
Dim objShell
Do
Choice = InputBox( _
    " ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER. . ." & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
    " 1 -  Check PC Name" & vbCrlf & _
    " 2 -  Change PC Name" & vbCrlf & _
    " 3 -  EXIT", "MENU")

Rem Gets the name of the Computer
strComputerName=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network").ComputerName

If (Choice <> vbNull) and (Choice <> "") Then
    Select Case Choice
    Case 1
        Wscript.Echo strComputerName
    Case 2
        Dim Input
        Input = InputBox ("Enter Name", "New Name")
        If Input = "" Then
            MsgBox "Change Canceled!"
        Else
            WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell").Run _
            "wmic computersystem where name="&chr(39)&strComputerName&chr(39)&" call rename name="&Input&"",0,false
        End If
    Case 3
        WScript.Quit
        Case Else
        'Wscript.Echo "bye"
    End Select
End If
Loop Until Choice = ""
```

---

```bat
ObjShell.run"wmic computersystem where name=""%computername%"" call rename name=""& Input"""
```

- Para expandir a variável `%ComputerName%` no código, você pode usar:

```bat
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%ComputerName%")
wshShell = Nothing
```


        <sup>***lincado com Rob van der Woude's Sript Pages - Environment Variables***</sup>

- Em uma linha sem criar variável para quando é usado uma só vez em todo o script

```bat
WScript.Echo (CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ComputerName%"))
```

- Em uma linha salvando em variável e usado mais de uma vez no script

```bat
strComputerName = (CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ComputerName%"))
WScript.Echo strComputerName
```

Então perceba que no seu código, não há **valor expandido** da variável `ComputerName` sendo passado para o `.Run WMIC` usar, tente:

Pegue o nome do computador antes e independente do `Case` que for escolhido.
Use antes de entrar no `if() else()` **Menu**, você vai usá-los tanto para `Case 1` como `Case 2`:

```bat
    If (Choice  vbNull) and (Choice  "") Then
         Select Case Choice
           ⇉  Case 1
                ⇢ Rem Gets the name of the Computer
                ⇢ set WshNetwork=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
                ⇢ strComputerName=WshNetwork.ComputerName
                                      ⇊
                ⇢ Wscript.Echo strComputerName
           ⇉  Case 2
                 Dim Input
                 Input = InputBox ("Enter Name", "New Name")
                 If Input = "" Then
                     MsgBox "Change Canceled!"
                 Else
                     'MsgBox ("You typed :" & Input)
                     set Objshel=WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")    ⇊
                  ⇢ ObjShell.run "wmic computersystem where name=""%computername%"" call rename name=""& Input"""
                     Set objshel=Nothing
                 End If
```

- Ficando....

```bat
⇢ Rem Gets the name of the Computer
⇢ set WshNetwork=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
⇢ strComputerName=WshNetwork.ComputerName

    If (Choice  vbNull) and (Choice  "") Then
         Select Case Choice
           ⇉  Case 1                  ⇊
                ⇢ Wscript.Echo strComputerName
           ⇉  Case 2
                 Dim Input
                 Input = InputBox ("Enter Name", "New Name")
                 If Input = "" Then
                     MsgBox "Change Canceled!"
                 Else
                     'MsgBox ("You typed :" & Input)
                     set Objshel=WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")   ⇊
                  ⇢ ObjShell.run "wmic computersystem where name=""ComputerName"" call rename name=""& Input"""
                     Set objshel=Nothing
                 End If
```

**Obs.: 1.** A falta de espaço entre `ObjShell.run+ESPAÇO+"wmic..."`, estou entendendo como *mero erro de edição/digitação* no momento de postar a sua pergunta.

```bat
            ⇩
ObjShell.run"wmic computersystem where name=""%computername%"" call rename name=""& Input"""
```

**Obs.: 2.** O `wmic` aceita o uso de semi aspas em `nome='str...'`, e tenho popr preferencia usá-lo na substituição por aspas duplas, e pode ser melhor de alinhar os escapings numa string de comando que também vai utilizar as aspas duplas, bastando uso do **[`chr()`](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/c60e2712-20e6-40f2-8fe2-cfb74ca6bca1.asp)**, como usei com o **`' == chr(29)`**

**Obs.: 4.** A variável `%ComputerName%` só vai assumir o valor novo após reiniciar, ao usa a sequência abaixo, o nome atual não vai atualizar para o nome nome:

- Ao usar:  `Case 1` exibe nome atual
- Ao usar:  `Case 2` troca o nome
- Ao usar:  `Case 1` **após** o `Case 2` vai exibir nome atual, não o novo!

**Obs.: 5.** Você precisa executar o seu script como administrador para alterar o nome do computador, uma possível solução (não testada) para elevar a execução, seria adicionar as linhas abaixo:

```bat
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName, _
  """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Dim objShell

Do
    Choice = InputBox( _
        " ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER. . ." & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & _
        " 1 -  Check PC Name" & vbCrlf & _
        " 2 -  Change PC Name" & vbCrlf & _
        " 3 -  EXIT", "MENU")

   Rem Gets the name of the Computer
   strComputerName=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network").ComputerName

   If (Choice <> vbNull) and (Choice <> "") Then

       Select Case Choice
       Case 1
           Wscript.Echo strComputerName
       Case 2
           Dim Input
           Input = InputBox ("Enter Name", "New Name")
           If Input = "" Then
               MsgBox "Change Canceled!"
           Else
               WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell").Run _
               "wmic computersystem where name="&chr(39)&strComputerName&chr(39)&" call rename name="&Input&"",0,false
           End If
       Case 3
           WScript.Quit
       Case Else
            Wscript.Echo "bye"
            WScript.Quit
       End Select

   End If

Loop Until Choice = ""
```